# How to apply substitution to text in a function in Vim

Tags: function, vim

I know that I can get all the text of the buffer in a function using following code:

```
let alltext = getline(1,'$')
```

I also know that following command adds line numbers to all lines in the buffer:

```
:%!cat -n
```

However, I am trying to get all text in a function and then add line numbers to this text for further processing.

Following do not work:

```
let alltext = %!cat -n
```

or:

```
let alltext = %s!cat -n
```

I do not think following is the right approach (I did not try it since it is system command and my seriously misfire):

```
function Myfn()
   let alltext = getline(1,'$')  
   echo alltext | !cat -n
endfunction
```

How can I add line numbers to `alltext` in above function so that subsequent `echo alltext` will show all lines with numbers prefixed? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[range]!cat -n` is only "useful" (if ever) in normal mode.

In a scripting context you will need to think differently. The method below uses `:help map()` and will work in Vim 7.4 and up:

```
function! Myfn()
   let alltext = getline(1,'$')
   echo alltext
   call map(alltext, 'v:key + 1 . " " . v:val')
   echo alltext
endfunction
```

Assuming the following content:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

the function above will output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['1 foo', '2 bar', '3 baz']
```

See `:help map()` and `:help lambda`.

If you only care about Vim 8 and up, you can use the new lambda syntax:

```
function! Myfn()
   let alltext = getline(1,'$')
   echo alltext
   call map(alltext, {key, val -> key + 1 . ' ' . val})
   echo alltext
endfunction
```

Comment: It is not working; I am getting error: `E121: Undefined variable: key`

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: I am using Gvim (Vim version 7.4.576) on Debian Stable Linux.